# How does Object get Function.prototype methods?

Tags: javascript

I tried to figure out how the Object constructor can have methods like `call` and `apply` since its prototype does not have them as properties, AND `Object.hasOwnProperty('call')` returns false in my current browser ( chromium ).

Please explain me where is this magic from

**I edit my question since some people don't seem to understand what I mean :**

A function inherits `call` from its prototype

```
var a = function(){}
a.hasOwnProperty('call') // false
a.prototype.hasOwnProperty('call') // true
```

`Object` has the `call` method. However, `Object.prototype` does not have the `call` method :

```
Object.hasOwnProperty('call') // false
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('call') // false
```

but `'call' in Object` outputs `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object` is a function - it's a constructor that can be used to create objects:

```
var foo = new Object();
```

Of course, usually you would just use an object literal:

```
var foo = {};
```

Note that:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) === Function.prototype // true
```

but:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) !== Object.prototype // true
```

It's not two prototypes - `Object` is a function, which creates objects that have the prototype `Object.prototype`. `Object` itself has the prototype `Function.prototype`

Comment: Thanks ! I forgot again that Object.getPrototypeOf was the one to use

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function Fn() {};
Fn.prototype.pro = "this_pro";
var object = new Fn();
object.prototype = {};

object.hasOwnProperty("pro"); # false
object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("pro"); # false
"pro" in object; # true
```

and this:

```
object.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("pro") #true
```

and usually, an object should not have the properties of its prototype as it self's propeties. these properties is  for the object which is a instance of it(as a function). To make is more clear:

```
object.__proto__ === Fn.prototype; # true
```